# What are some good blogs to follow in the RIA space?

Tags: ajax, flash, silverlight, user-interface, ria

so far, I found Anthony Franco, Raju Bitter...but I want to know what others follow:

I want some really good blogs to track RIA, UI Design, Ajax, Silverlight, Flash, Flex..

Answer (score 2):

Here's one you might want to check out: http://www.silverlightcream.com

Comment: that is a nice link +1. But I am also looking similar links for flex and others.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out ajaxian.com

Answer (score 0):

For Design http://www.smashingmagazine.com/ , has a lot of tutorials and information client part of the webapp (CSS, javascript, HTML, etc).

Answer (score 0):

[Feed Squirrel](http://www.feed-squirrel.com/) aggregates an assortment of RIA blogs.

Comment: Hmmm, that's odd - I'm fairly sure the buy behind it works with Silverlight.

Maybe try contacting him and asking if he has plans to add such a category?

Comment: Ooops, "...the buy behind it..." = "...the guy behind it..." !

Answer (score 0):

Lots of great stuff on Flex, Silverlight, WPF, Surface and UX Design:

http://www.cynergysystems.com/blogs/

Answer (score 0):

Follow the projects themselves, too. Here's the [news feed for Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/company/news-press/).